# How can I extract raw data from a .tiff image in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, image, tiff, feature-extraction

I have some project wherein I have to manipulate some raw data from an image generated which is in `.tiff` format. I only have access to the image location. Now, I want to extract some raw info from the image like number of pixels in the image, no. of bits per pixel, no. of color components, etc.

I am working on a project on MAC OS and thus, to talk to Apple APIs, `Objective-C` is being used.

Can anyone suggest some techniques or some Apple APIs, if possible, which can assist me in extracting the desired from the image?

P.S.: I actually preferred `.tiff` format since `.jpeg` is a lossy compression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this code will help you a bit, NSImage already contains width and height, so you can count number of pixels.

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[@"~/Desktop/image.tiff" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
NSData *imageData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)CFBridgingRetain(imageData), NULL);
CGImageRef imageRef =  CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
NSUInteger numberOfBitsPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef);
NSLog(@"Number Of Bits Per Pixel %lu", (unsigned long)numberOfBitsPerPixel);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer.. this is working. Could you also tell me how could I extract the `pixelDataType` info from this `NSData` or `NSImage`?

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://uri-labs.com/macosx_headers/ICScannerBandData_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/property_DONTLINK_12)

Comment: Also, how can I get the number of rows in the image?

Comment: There's a whole example regarding your link, which shows how to do it: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/VirtualScanner/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011006-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: In the project, there is no mention of the information that is required by me: `number of rows` in the image and `pixelDatatype`. Anyways, I can manipulate the `pixelDataType` for now. So, regarding the `no. of rows`- is it same as the `height` of the image..?(I don't think so). If not, then how can I get that information?